# Spring security 4, how to disable login-page but not login-processing-url?

Tags: rest, spring-security, configuration

I am trying to implement a REST login, so I don't want an URL rendering a form.
This is my configuration:

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint">
    <security:form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="restEntryPoint"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="restEntryPoint"/>
    <security:logout success-handler-ref="restEntryPoint"/>
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>
```

The URL used for the form and the login is `/login`.

How do I disable the `GET /login` without having to write something like:

```
<security:form-login login-page="/jsdklfjslbuulundnn___kdjfkjfdkjvvj"
```

but `login-processing-url` remains active?

Comment: You're just gonna send `form-url-encoded` username and password through a `POST`? if so, why not HTTP Basic?

Comment: Because I want to see if it is possible to do it in the other way :P Will check that, thanks for the suggestion. Anyway, I appreciate an answer for the main question.

Comment: @AliDehghani: after checking your suggestion, it seems I would lose the optional "Remember me", isn't it? so HTTP Basic does not fit for me :( Thank you. I hope someone has the answer to the main question.